# MariaDB 10.8.x Strict Mode always ON?

Tags: mysql, debian, permissions, mariadb

I'm installing MariaDB on a new Debian 11 server and transferring my projects but I have a problem.
STRICT MODE is always ENABLED on MariaDB.

I check many sites, and try to add the string `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` in the section [mysqld] file /etc/my.cnf. And in [mariadb] section I try `innodb_strict_mode=OFF`

Command `mysqld --verbose --help` says ALL OK, sql_mode right, strict mode is OFF.

But when I login to mysql and make `SELECT @@sql_mode, @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;`
I get the result: `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_...` - NO EFFECT

If I SET variables in MYSQL - I get it for the session.
I try to add this command to the beginning of my script and get an error (need SUPER Priv for user)...

How can I disable strict mode?

Comment: Did you make any changes to my.cnf?  That is where permanent changes for all users need to be made.

Comment: Yes, I did. And I see changes in "mysqld --verbose --help", but when I open mysql (from console or PHP script) - no changes.

Comment: Move to dba.stackexchange.com